# C++11 ambiguity between declarator and abstract-declarator in parameter clause?

Tags: c++, c++11, most-vexing-parse

Consider the following C++11 code:

```
struct C {};

void f(int(C));
```

Is the type of `f` the same as:

```
typedef int T(C);
void f(T);
```

or is it like:

```
void f(int C);
```

That is, should the `(C)` be interpreted as a `declarator` of the parameter name `C`, or as an `abstract-declarator` of a function parameter ?

Where is this specified in the standard?

Comment: This is `void f(int(*)(C))` - hello, MVP! :)

Comment: @Xeo: Sure, where is the ambiguity resolved in the standard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is specified in 8.2p7

> 7
>   Another ambiguity arises in a parameter-declaration-clause of a function declaration, or in a type-id that
>   is the operand of a sizeof or typeid operator, when a type-name is nested in parentheses. In this case,
>   the choice is between the declaration of a parameter of type pointer to function and the declaration of a
>   parameter with redundant parentheses around the declarator-id. The resolution is to consider the type-name
>   as a simple-type-specifier rather than a declarator-id.

Hence, your parameter has type `int(*)(C)`, as you show in your first possible interpretation.